# Creating a list of dictionaries where each dictionary contains another dictionary as values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

Im writing an algorithm in Python which plays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTZsH.jpg) game.

The current state of the board of tiles in the game is a dictionary in the form of:

```
{
    <tile_id>: {
                'counters': <number of counters on tile or None>,
                'player': <player id of the player who holds the tile or None>,
                'neighbours': <list of ids of neighbouring tile>
               },
               ...
}
```

I have another dictionary which stores all of my tiles which are 'full' (i.e. a tile which has one less counter than its number of neighbours and where the `player` is me) This dictionary, `full_tiles`, is in the same form as the `board` dictionary above.

I am now trying to create a list, `chains`, where each element in the list is a dictionary of my full tiles that are neighbouring at least one other full tile (i.e a chain of full tiles). So this will be a list of all my seperate chains on the board.

Here is my code so far:

```
for tile_id, tile in full_tiles.items(): #iterates through all full tiles
    current_tile = {tile_id : tile}      #temporarily stores current tile
    if not chains:                       #if chains list is empty
        chains.append(current_tile)      #begin list
    else:                                #if list is not empty
        for index, chain in enumerate(chains):            #iterate though list of chains
            if not (current_tile in chain):               #if current tile is not in current chain
                for tile_id2, tile2 in chain.items():     #iterate through tiles in current chain
                    for neighbour in tile2["neighbours"]: #iterate through each neighbour of current tile
                                                          #neighbour is in the form of tile_id
                        if neighbour in chain:            #if current tile's neighbour is in chain
                            chain[tile_id] = tile         #add tile to chain
```

It is very difficult for me to test and debug my code and check if it is working correctly as the code can only be run in an application that simulates the game. As you can see, there is quite a lot going on in this block of code with all of the nested loops which are difficult to follow. I cannot seem to think straight at the minute and so I cannot determine if this mess, in all honesty, will function as I hope.

While I am writing this, I have just realised that - on line 7 of this code - I am only checking if the current tile is not in the current chain and so there will be intersecting chains which, of course, will be a mess. Instead of this, I need to first check if the current tile is in not in *any* of the chains, not just one.

Apart from this error, will my code achieve what I am attempting? Or can you recommend a simpler, neater way to do it? (There has to be!)

Also, let me know if I have not given enough information on how the code is run or if I need to explain anything further, such as the contents of the `board` dictionary.

Thank you for any help in advance.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, I was under a time constraint to complete this project, and as it was my first time ever working with Python, I currently lack the knowledge in the language to optimise my solution using the sources given below. Here is my final ***extremely ugly and messy*** solution to this problem which, in the end, worked fine and wasn't terribly inefficient given the small data set that the code works on.

```
for x in range(0, len(my_hexplode_chains) - 1):
    match_found = False
    for y in range(x + 1, len(my_hexplode_chains)):
        for tile_id_x, tile_x in my_hexplode_chains[x].items():             #compare each chain in list
            for tile_id_y, tile_y in my_hexplode_chains[y].items():         #to every other chain
                for neighbour in tile_x["neighbours"]:                      #if tiles in different lists
                    if neighbour == tile_id_y:                              #are neighbours
                        match_found = True
                        my_hexplode_chains[x].update(my_hexplode_chains[y]) #append one chain to the other
                        del my_hexplode_chains[y]                           #delete appended chain
                if match_found:                                             #continue loop at next chain
                    break                                                   #very ugly way to do this
            if match_found:
                break
        if match_found:
            break
    if match_found:
        break
```

Comment: This is a graph problem. Graphs in Python are most easily represented as dictionaries of node, adj-list pairs. You could probably do this using comprehensions pretty simply.

Comment: @erip Unfortunately, I am brand new to Python and only began learning it in order to complete this challenge. I really don't undertsand what you have recommended but I will research it now. Thanks

Comment: Definitely not unfortunate. :) I'm glad to see you're learning! [This](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) is a pretty good description of comprehensions. If you're familiar with set-builder notation in mathematics, it's similar to that.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) also have a very nice description of a good graph implementation. You'll need to make some modifications, though. Instead of a character mapping to a list of characters, you might want to implement a `Tile` class and map it to a list of `Tile`s.

Comment: Thank you for the two resources, I'll study them now. However, due to the nature of this challenge, all of my code must be submitted in a single function and so I cannot create new classes

Comment: @CornOnTheKob are you still dealing with this problem?

Comment: @mabe02 yes, I was under a time constraint and this was my first ever time working with Python. My understanding of the language and its data structures wasn't yet sufficient enough to come up with a solution from the sources given by erip above. My finished solution had a similar approach of what I gave in the question. It is a very ugly and quite messy piece of code, but it works perfectly and wasn't extremely inefficient. Why do you ask?

Comment: @CornOnTheKob I was curious if you wanted to optimized this solution. This would have been fun

Comment: @mabe02 unfortuantely, not yet. I began learning Python to tackle this project and so hope to continue studying the langauge. Maybe when I have a better understanding I can come back and optimise this code. I will post my final solution as an edit to my question.

Comment: @CornOnTheKob I played a little around your code and I  hope you will find it interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this optimization?

```
def find_match (my_hexplode_chains):

    x =  0
    len_chain = len(my_hexplode_chains)
    while x <= len_chain:
        y = x + 1
        for tile_id_x, tile_x in my_hexplode_chains[x].items():
            for tile_id_y, tile_y in my_hexplode_chains[y].items():
                if tile_id_y in tile_x["neighbours"]:
                    my_hexplode_chains[x].update(my_hexplode_chains[y])
                    del my_hexplode_chains[y]
                    return True
        x += 1
    return False
```

You could pass this function after each move in your game and trace the output.

Comment: This is the best and most efficient solution so far, but I'm sure there is definitely a less clustered way to structure this using some data structure.